# Аналог MySQL limit n,m в Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Можно ли как-нибудь организовать возможность вывода части запроса с `n` по `m` позиции также как это реализовано в MySQL добавлением к запросу `limit n,m`?

Есть решение, обернуть в несколько запросов, но не подходящее из-за нагрузки на БД такими запросами при "средне-больших" таблиц:

```
select * from (select rownum as rn,* from ... where ...) d where d.rn between n and m
```

Да и скан показывает, что вложенный запрос весь ложится в память.

Можно ли как-то в первый запрос (вложенный) подставить `n` и `m`?

Comment: <pre>
select * from ... where rownum > 10 and rownum < 20
</pre>
Ну либо я чего-то не понял :)

Comment: Так работать не будет, запрос выдаст 0 записей) Логика такая: получаем из запроса по другим условиям первую запись, у нее rownum=1-смотрим на условие, не подходит, слудующую, а у следующей тоже равно 1, она же первая. В итоге ноль записей)

Answer (score 4):

Привет, ребята из 2011, я сейчас в 2015 году и мы делаем так:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 3):

В версии 12.01 для TopN запросов была добавлена новая клауза [*row_limiting_clause*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702).
Вот её синтактическая диаграмма:

```
[ OFFSET offset { ROW | ROWS } ]
[ FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ { rowcount | percent PERCENT } ]
    { ROW | ROWS } { ONLY | WITH TIES } ]
```

**Следует обязательно учесть**, что без сортировки с `ORDER BY` эта клауза будет работать, но результат будет не детерминирован, то есть - источник трудно диагностируемой ошибки:

> For consistent results, **specify the order_by_clause to ensure a deterministic sort order**.

Простейший рабочий пример:

```
create table unordered (id) as
    select trunc (dbms_random.value (1,99)) from dual connect by level<=99
/    
select id from unordered
order by id desc
offset 77 rows fetch next 3 rows with ties 
/

        ID
----------
        17
        16
        15
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_merge IS
    SELECT * FROM DUAL;

    type c_merge_row_type is table of c_merge%rowtype;
    rec_merge c_merge_row_type;
BEGIN
    open c_merge;
    loop
    -- здесь устанавливаете размер "порции" для считывания
         fetch c_merge bulk collect into rec_merge limit 50;
         for i in 1..rec_merge.count loop
             // do something
         end loop;
         exit when c_merge%notfound;
    end loop;
    close c_merge;
END;
```

**Добавлено из комментария.**

Этот код - это 2 вложенных цикла, 1-ый возвращает вам записи:

- 0-50
- 51-100
- 101-150, итд

Второй уже обрабатывает каждую запись отдельно. Если вы хотите обработать только с 100 по 150 добавьте счетчик:

- counter:=0, записи 0-50
- counter:=1, записи 51-100
- counter:=2, записи 101-150

**UP**: вариант с bulk collect не очень удобен если вам нужно обработать последнюю "порцию" данных, эту проблему легко решить добавив/изменив ORDER BY условие в исходный запрос

Comment: А как задать с какого начать? К примеру мне нужно отобразить из запроса с 100 по 150 запись!

Comment: этот код это 2 вложенных цикла, 1ый возвращает вам записи:  
0-50  
51-100  
101-150, итд  

второй уже обрабатывает каждую запись отдельно.
если вы хотите обработать только с 100 по 150 добавьте счетчик  
counter:=0, записи 0-50  
counter:=1, записи 51-100  
counter:=2, записи 101-150

Comment: Это не есть хороший вариант. Если у меня таблица контрагентов на 1500 000 записей и мне надо последние выбрать?

Comment: Стоит заметить, я вас не совсем понимаю, это решение позволяет обработать все данные из набора. У вас конкретная задача обработать из всего набора только записи с rownum 100-150 (к примеру)?

Comment: В таком случае действительно удобнее в условии выборки указать нужный вам диапазон через rownum:  
and rownum > 150

Comment: rownum>N нельзя использовать. Пытался объяснить выше: попробуйте сами сделать... 

Хотя напишу: у первой выдаваемой строки в запросе чему равен rownum? Он равен 1! 1>N (где N = 150)? Нет! Строка выкидывается из запроса, в связи с несоотвествием условию. И так все строки.

Comment: У вас есть набор данных и вам нужно взять нное количество с конца, которое удовлетворяет условию. Но если вы будете игнорировать строки в начале, то естественно у них изменится rownum, т.к. он генерится динамически ораклом. Но с другой стороны никто не мешает вам отсортировать набор данных в обратном порядке. Тогда сделав rownum < 150, вы получите последних 150 записей. Нужно их отсортировать в обратном порядке? Добавьте еще 1 выборку с обратной сортировкой.

Answer (score 1):

Вот почитайте здесь: [возврат части отсортированной выборки](http://www.sql.ru/faq/faq_topic.aspx?fid=171).

> 1. Выдать записи с 10-й по 19-ю из выборки по представлению ALL_TABLES, отсортированной по полю TABLE_NAME:

```
select o.*
from (select rownum rw
           , o.*
      from (select o.* from all_tables o order by table_name) o
      where rownum < 20
     ) o
where o.rw >= 10;
```

> 2. Возрат части отсортированной выборки через аналитическую функцию ROW_NUMBER():

```
select o.*
from (select o.*
           , row_number() over (order by o.table_name) rw
      from all_tables o
     ) o
where o.rw >= 10
  and o.rw < 20;
```

Comment: У меня в вопросе почти тоже самое (переделаю примерно так):
select * from (select rownum as rn,* from ... where ... rn<m) d where d.rn>=n
Хочу без вложенных запросов!)

Comment: Тогда остается только процедура которая приведена предыдущим ответом, если откомпилить то еще быстрее будет.

Comment: Вложенный запрос не страшен. Оракл имеет очень эффективный оптимизатор запросов и он раскроет скобки и сделает всё как надо, так что беспокоиться не о чем.

Comment: В той процедуре не могу понять как стартовать с n позиции. Вернее думаю что предложать их впустую прогнать, но это не вариант!

Comment: С вложенным оракл раскрывает, но делает скан всего запроса, поэтому не подходит при больших таблицах. К примеру контрагенты на 1 500 000 пользователей с дампом в 50-100мб и обращений 100-1000 в секунду...